# Reduction in steepness

Tags: single-word-requests

I seek a word to describe the reduction in steepness of a slope. The context is climbing a hill that is less steep further up.

I have rejected "levelled" and "flattened" because they suggest the slope became near to horizontal when in fact it remained steep.

Answer (score 4):

You could say the steepness of the slope *eased*, or *became more gradual*, or if you're feeling a little adventurous you might go the adjective-to-verb route and say it *gentled*.

Comment: As a hillwalker, I'd go with eased - or possible shallowed

Comment: Or, if you want to be funny about it, you could say the hill degrades.... :-)

Comment: @Hellion: Good one. :)

Comment: @HorusKol: or also “shallowed out”, perhaps?  We certainly use that in my family, and while as far as I know that’s mainly an idiosyncratic usage, it’s a pretty transparent one — I’ve used it with other friends and they haven’t batted an eyelid.  You can also just say *the slope eased* — you don’t need to explicitly say *the steepness of the slope* in that construction.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative of elevation drops below zero?